# Matplotlib stacked histogram label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my picture. I need to make label for those bars however every upper layer contains lower layer - so the label should containt grouped colors, i.e. blue - dataset 1, blue/orange - dataset 2, blue/orange/green - dataset 3 and finally blue/orange/green/purple - dataset 4. Is it plausible to make it? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G2E8.png)

```
binwidth = 1
n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(C, bins=range(81, 105, binwidth), 
                   density=False, histtype='barstacked' ,
                        edgecolor='gray', 
                        color=barvy_histogram,linewidth=0.3)

hatches = ['//','x','..','oo']
for patch_set, hatch in zip(patches, hatches):
    for patch in patch_set.patches:
        patch.set_hatch(hatch)
        patch.set_linewidth=0.1
        patch.set_color='gray'
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach uses the tuple legend handler ([`HandlerTuple`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple)) to  combine the legend handles. It produces a horizontal layout, while maybe a vertical stacking would be more interesting.

The code starts with creating some test data, supposing `C` is an `Nx4` array of integers. The bin edges are set at halves to make sure that floating point accuracy wouldn't place values in the wrong bin.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import numpy as np

# first, create some test data
C = (np.random.normal(0.001, 1, (100, 20)).cumsum(axis=0) * 1.2 + 90).astype(int).reshape(-1, 4)
c_min = C.min()
c_max = C.max()

mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 0.5
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
binwidth = 1
colors = plt.cm.Set2.colors[:C.shape[1]]
_, _, patches = ax1.hist(C, bins=np.arange(c_min - 0.5, c_max + binwidth, binwidth),
                         density=False, histtype='barstacked',
                         edgecolor='gray', color=colors, linewidth=0.3,
                         label=[f'N={p}' for p in range(25, 101, 25)])

hatches = ['//', 'x', '..', 'oo']
for patch_set, hatch in zip(patches, hatches):
     for patch in patch_set.patches:
          patch.set_hatch(hatch)
          patch.set_linewidth = 0.1

handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(handles=[tuple(handles[:i + 1]) for i in range(C.shape[1])], labels=labels,
           handlelength=6, handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0)})
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib legend using HandlerTuple]